# Does git allow to delete objects found in a reference repository?

Tags: git

I create the cache git repo with `git clone --mirror ...`, then I periodically update it via cron, like `git remote update -p`.
On the need I also create some local repos with `git clone --reference <local repo> ...` and work with them - pulling, commiting and pushing.

How can I delete from my repos the git objects that have appeared in the cache repo? - The remote repo is a very huge one, and I don't want to waste my space.